# Looping through two column at the same time in laravel

Tags: laravel, loops, foreach

I want to get the values of two columns and loop through the two of them at the same time and use it to calculate the distance using latitude and longitude but the problem is that it loops for all the latitude for mechanics and loop for all the longitude for mechanics but the two should be combined as one.

```
            $mechanicsLatitude = DB::table("tranxav_mechanics")->get(['latitude','email']);
            $mechanicsLongitude = DB::table("tranxav_mechanics")->get(['longitude', 'email']);

              foreach ($mechanicsLatitude as $latitudeData){
                  foreach ($mechanicsLongitude as $longitudeData){
                       $theta = $driverLongitude - $longitudeData->longitude;
                      $dist = sin(deg2rad($driverLatitude)) * 
                              sin(deg2rad($latitudeData->latitude)) 
                          +  cos(deg2rad($driverLatitude)) 
                          * cos(deg2rad($latitudeData->latitude)) 
                          * cos(deg2rad($theta));
                        $dist = acos($dist);
                       $dist = rad2deg($dist);
                       $miles = $dist * 60 * 1.1515;
                      $unit = strtoupper("K");

                      if ($unit == "K") {
                        return $miles =  $miles * 1.609344;
                      } elseif ($unit == "N") {
                            $miles = $miles * 0.8684;
                      } else {
                            $miles;
                      }

                        TranxavTransaction::create([
                            'dEmail' => $request->get("email"),
                            'mEmail' => $longitudeData->email,
                            'car_model' => $model,
                            'how_it_happened' => $request->get("likelyProblem"),
                            'latitude' => $request->get("latitude"),
                            'longitude' => $request->get("longitude"),
                            'problem' => input::get('likelyProblem')
                        ]);
                    }
                 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using a foreach, you can a simple for loop with indexes:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < $mechanicsLatitude->count(); $i++)
    $theta = $driverLongitude - $mechanicsLongitude[$i]->longitude;
    .
    .
    .
```

And make sure that *$mechanicsLatitude* and *$mechanicsLongitude* have the same length.